# Do tuples use special syntax?

Tags: haskell, operators

I'm learning haskell. I know that infix operator can be used in two ways:

- `(+) 1 2`
- `1 + 2`

But what about tuples? I can write: `(,) 1 2` but I can't write `1 , 2`. Why? Why do I have to use parenthesis and write `(1,2)`? Is it some kind of special syntax or i'm just missing something?

Comment: You can also write `(,,) 1 2 3` for `(1, 2, 3)`, but `1 ,, 2 3` would make for some confusing syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, tuple syntax is special. Tuple *types* are special too (syntactic sugar for a `data` type with a single variant). Note that `(a, b, c)` and `((a, b), c)` and `(a, (b, c))` are all distinct types: Unlike ordinary operators, tuple construction is not just a binary operation that can be nested, there are n-ary tuple construction operators for (virtually) any n. Special casing the binary case wouldn't be considered elegant, I suppose.

Trying to allow n-ary tuple construction without parentheses can also make for a more complicated grammar with some surprising corner cases (cf. Python).

Comment: Any examples about corner cases in Python ?

Comment: @mb14 In many contexts, commas are used for purposes other than tuple construction/unpacking (e.g. `with cm1 as x, cm2 as y:`, `except E1, E2:`, `func(arg1, arg2)`, `assert cond, msg`) and using a tuple there requires parentheses for disambiguation. All of these make sense, and most aren't surprising to most people, but many people stumble over at least one of these at some point.